# How to get php array by ajax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I tried to access **PHP** array, I am not able to access it. It remains silent when I run the code. Here I use javascript to get php through get method of ajax. The createRequest() function is used as creating request object. Then the getDetails() is used to coordinate displayDetails() and createRequest(). The php file is shown below. Any assistance will be helpful,

```
function createRequest() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (otherMS) {
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (failed) {
        request = null;
    }
    }
    }
return request;
}

function getDetails() {
    alert("getDetails");
    request = createRequest();
    if (request==null) {
        alert("Unable to create request");
        return;
    }


    request.open("GET","problems.php",true);
    request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
    request.send(null);
}

function displayDetails() {

    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {

            detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");

            var jsumset = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            detailDiv.innerHTML = jsumset["rop"];
        }
    }
}


<?php
    include ("sumcreator.php");
    $sumobj = new sumcreator();
    $sumset = $sumobj->sumcreator();

    echo $json_encode($sumset);
?>
```

Comment: are you sure `JSON.parse` is working, have you debugged it ?

Comment: instead using `XMLHttpRequest` you should use some javascript frameworks for example, `jquery` etc.. it will be more flexible and cross browser compitable.

Comment: Abstracting XMLHttpRequest can only *reduce* flexibility. jQuery can't make it any more cross-browser compatible then this code already is (since it handles the pre-standard XHR from old-IE).

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging and figure out where the problem is. Does the PHP work if you request it directly? Does the `displayDetails` fire at all? Does the readyState ever ready `4`? What is the `request.status`? Can you see the HTTP request being sent in your browser's developer tools Net tab? What about the response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Through jquery you don't have to concern about the cross browser compatibility, because you have to just use abstracted methods.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use UTF8 encoding. Json functions require it so if you're using any accented characters, you should have them utf8_encode -d.

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing it in two methods you can do it in one functionlike this
You can try this if it works:

```
function addMe() {

        theValues = document.getElementById('list2');


         for(i = 0; i < theValues.length; i++) {



                if (   document.getElementById('theNumbers').value == ""   ) {
                    document.getElementById('theNumbers').value ="`"+theValues[i].value+"`";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('theNumbers').value += ","+"`"  + theValues[i].value+"`";
                }



        }


var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
//alert(jsonString);
            $('#test').html("");
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pages/ajaxpage.php",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(response){



           $('#test').html(response);


        }
    });

    }

    }
```